# Primefaces selectBooleanCheckbox not displaying in the correct position

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog which will show a pop-up windows with 2 checkbox, the first is checked and the second is unchecked as the code below:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label-container,field-container">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="true" />
    <h:outputText value="EDIT SHEETS" />

    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="false" />
    <h:outputText value="EDIT OTHERS" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

But the first hook symbol wasn't in the checkbox center. If I click no matter where, the symbol will be suddenly in the correct position.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is is happening is any specific browser or any specific version of browser?Cause it's fine when I used it.

Comment: @SrinivasR It happened in any browser, I use chrome and IE

Comment: Please create and show a copy'n'paste'n'runnable SSCCE.

Comment: Please also provide primefaces version

Comment: @Jitesh I'm using the version 3.3.1

Comment: It should work fine until any of your css overriding it's default. Please provide detail of label-container,field-container class.

Comment: @Jitesh here it is
    .label-container {
 padding-bottom:5px;
}

.field-container {
    font-weight:bold;
    white-space:nowrap
}

Comment: I don't think there is problem with your class. Please check, the change in html code while clicking on checkbox using firebug or google chrome. I'm using 3.3.1 for my application from a long and I never have faced this problem. So check the change and try to find the change in html code on clicking checkbox

Comment: @Jitesh Ok! I don't know exactly how to use chrome to check..I'm sorry I'm really noob on HTML...

Comment: Just right click on the desired component(checkbox in your case) in chrome, click on "inspect element" and at the bottom it will show the html code which are generated for your checkbox. You will find the change in html code after clicking on checkbox.

Comment: @Jitesh OK I found it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you find anything, that causing this misbehavior ??

Comment: @Jitesh sorry for replying so late, I didn't find anything wrong with the html debug...

Answer (score 0):

You should use value="#{true}" instead of value="true"

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label-container,field-container">
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{true}" />
<h:outputText value="EDIT SHEETS" />

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{false}" />
<h:outputText value="EDIT OTHERS" />
```